# How do I specify the key file that capistrano will use when cloning the repository on the remote server?

Tags: capistrano

Ideally, I want something  like `set :scm_keyfile, "~/.ssh/server-deploy-key"`. The path specified would of course be a path on the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the remote user already has a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` then `git` will use it by default.

If you wish to use an alternate file name for your private key, you can do this. Create a file on your remote server `~/.ssh/config` and put these lines in it

```
Host github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server-deploy-key
```

Now when you attempt to run a command like `git clone git@github.com/xxx/yyy.git`, Your `~/.ssh/server-deploy-key` will be used.

Another method is to use ssh-agent forwarding. In this method, you don't need to put your deploy key on the remote server. As long as it is on your local machine, and you have enabled ssh-agent forwarding, your remote server will have access to the key and will use it . There is a [nice article on github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) explaining this.